# Nuovo uso del verbo “agevolare”

Tags: meaning, etymology

Questo [post](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2019/01/18/significato-agevolare-informazioni/) di un blog di linguistica pone il problema dell'origine del senso recente, risalente agli ultimi anni, con cui viene spesso usato soprattutto in ambito “social” il verbo **agevolare**: cioè, anziché “rendere agevole, facilitare” (detto di una cosa) oppure “aiutare, favorire” (detto di una persona), viene usato per dire “fornire, allegare”. Si leggono espressioni come “agevolo una foto esplicativa” o “agevolo intervista completa” (più esempi nel post citato).

Lì ci si chiede – e io ripropongo qui il quesito – da dove provenga questo uso. Ha un'origine regionale? Deriva da qualche tormentone?

Comment: Concordo con i commenti al blog che venga da “Striscia la notizia”, con “agevoliamo il filmato”.

Comment: Che tristezza. Sempre che non sia usato con ovvio riferimento alla trasmissione. ..Ezio Greggio senza tormentoni non esisterebbe.  Con la G di nafta non era male:)

Comment: Nel GDLI si può trovare un'accezione di [agevolare](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI01/GDLI_01_ocr_242.pdf&parola=agevolare) con il significato di fornire, provvedere

Comment: Il commento qui sopra conferma che l'utente @egreg è, in realtà, **e**zio **greg**gio.